# ¿Por qué me da error que falta una referencia de ensamblado?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Estoy teniendo error al ejecutar la aplicación por un espacio de nombres o referencia de ensamblado.
Tengo la clase TransportistasBLL, que esta en la carpeta BLL dentro de la carpeta App_Code. y he agregado la referencia

```
using Examen4.App_Code.BLL;
```

Al crear la instancia de dicha clase, al parecer si "reconoce" la clase para crear el objeto, y a la vez puedo acceder al método de Insertar

```
 TransportistasBLL oj = new TransportistasBLL();
 oj.InsertarTrans(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text, TextBox4.Text, TextBox5.Text, TextBox6.Text);
```

Pero siempre aparece el error que no se encontró la clase transportistasBLL.

```
Error   CS0234  El tipo o el nombre del espacio de nombres 'BLL' no existe en el espacio de nombres 'Examen4.App_Code' (¿falta alguna referencia de ensamblado?)    Examen4 C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Examen4\Examen4\App_Code\WebForm1.aspx.cs   1   Activo
```

Incluso me llevé el formulario dentro la carpetaApp_Code y siempre me da el error.

Acá muestro en captura general el error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La clase transportistasBLL es la siguientes

```
namespace Examen4.App_Code.BLL
{
public class TransportistasBLL
{
    public TransportistasBLL() { }

    public void InsertarTrans(string nombre, string direccion, string ciudad, 
    string region, string telefono, string pais)
    {
        TransporteDSTableAdapters.TransportistasTableAdapter adaptador = new 
        TransporteDSTableAdapters.TransportistasTableAdapter();
        adaptador.Insert(nombre, direccion, ciudad, region, telefono, pais);
    }

}
}
```

WebForm1.aspx

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
     <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="id_transportista" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="id_transportista" HeaderText="id_transportista" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="id_transportista" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="nombre_empresa" HeaderText="nombre_empresa" SortExpression="nombre_empresa" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="direccion" HeaderText="direccion" SortExpression="direccion" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ciudad" HeaderText="ciudad" SortExpression="ciudad" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="region" HeaderText="region" SortExpression="region" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="telefono" HeaderText="telefono" SortExpression="telefono" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="pais" HeaderText="pais" SortExpression="pais" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="codigo" HeaderText="codigo" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="codigo" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" DeleteMethod="Delete" InsertMethod="Insert" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectMethod="MostrarTransportistas" TypeName="TransporteDSTableAdapters.TransportistasTableAdapter" UpdateMethod="Update">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Original_Expr1" Type="Int32" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Expr2" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Expr3" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ciudad" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="region" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="telefono" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="pais" Type="String" />
        </InsertParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Expr2" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Expr3" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ciudad" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="region" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="telefono" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="pais" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Original_Expr1" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="id_transportista" Type="Int32" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>

</div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="btnInsertTrans" runat="server" Text="Insertar" OnClick="btnInsertTrans_Click" />
</form>
```

La clase del Webform:

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;
 using System.Web.UI;
 using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
 using Examen4.App_Code.BLL;

 namespace Examen4.App_Code
 {
 public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
 {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void btnInsertTrans_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TransportistasBLL oj = new TransportistasBLL();
        oj.InsertarTrans(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text, 
        TextBox4.Text, TextBox5.Text, TextBox6.Text);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: El código como texto, por favor.

Comment: añadi la declaracion de tu clase que tiene problemas

Comment: el problema está en el webform, agrega el código de ello

Comment: Te hace referencia a tu carpeta BLL que declaraste en el using, probaste quitarla?

Comment: Donde hago la instancia a la clase TransportistaBLL es lo que tengo en el evento click del boton del webform @fredyfx

Comment: @RamiroBarone cuando la quito no reconoce la clase TransportistasBLL

Comment: Probaste limpiar y recompilar de nuevo?

Comment: Edita la pregunta y agrega el código que tienes en `WebForm1.aspx.cs` + `WebForm1.aspx`

Comment: Si amigo, probé haciendo eso tambien @RamiroBarone

Comment: Es raro el error ya que esta todo, se me ocurren cosas como que la direccion es muy larga en las carpetas aunque la estuve mirando y no lo es. Otra cosa seria probar borrar el archivo de la clase y volver a crearlo, por supuesto copia el codigo y cambiale de nombre para quitar sospecha de que el nombre quedo grabado y no se limpio correctamente.